# How can I solve my TrueCrypt installation problem?

Tags: installation, truecrypt

I downloaded the truecrypt 64 bit .tar.gz, but it could not be opened. The archiv manager says: Does not look like a tar archiv. Does anybody no, how to solve this error? 
OS :Ubuntu Maverick.
On Lucid I had no problems to install TrueCrypt.

Comment: I've downloaded the archiv and tried to extract it and it worked fine -- just try to download the file again (maybe it's corrupted).

Comment: Run `md5sum truecrypt-7.0a-linux-x64.tar.gz`. It should give the checksum 1eb6c349514d74a46aa32cf4c27befeb. What archive manager are you using? They should support gzip-compressed tarballs.

Answer (score 1):

This is an execelent [post](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2010/09/encrypt-thumb-drives-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat-truecrypt/) to install Truecrypt in ubuntu 10.10 maverick

TO un-install just use :

> sudo sh
>   /usr/bin/truecrypt-uninstall.sh